# How to upload image using raw in POSTMAN?

Tags: django, request, image-upload, postman

I am trying to upload an image using POSTMAN. I succeed with form-data but not with passing data in raw JSON format.

> request through form-data in POSTMAN:

[image]

> request through curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "profile_image=@/home/shivani/Pictures/Wallpapers/8018.jpg" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/image/
{"message":"Image Uploaded successfully.","profile_image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/aubergine-solutions/image/upload/v1430204993/w0oxhv6beaxd14twrxmi.jpg"}~
```

When I send request in raw as:

[image]

I get the following error though i have added MultiPartParser in Django settings:

[image]

Can anybody help to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, just to specify if anyone is running into this problem that if you want to upload image using json then base64 string of image needs to be attached like
`"profile_image": {
        "name": "72397.jpg",
        "content_type":"image/jpg",
        "file":"base64string"}`
or either way is "form-data"

Comment: I'm also having same issue now. And I need to pass basic data with image. Can you give me the code, how you are passing image with raw data.

Answer (score 7):

When i'm using the image upload, i encoded the image using base64,and that encoded string is passed as json string.In the backend we can decoded the string and make the image.Try this, i think it works.